# Legend does not appear in holoviews for only 1 line

Tags: python, legend, holoviews

I have learned that holoviews is [for some reasons](https://github.com/pyviz/holoviews/issues/2339) not able to show a legend for hv.HLine. To bipass this problem I created a horizontal line by using hv.Curve. I now would like to add a legend for this curve but it does not appear in the plot. However, if a second curve is used in an overlay the legend appears:

```
p = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,3,4,5],'b':[5,5,5,5,5,5],'c':[4.8,4.8,4.8,4.8,4.8,4.8]})
curve1 = hv.Curve(p,'a','b', label = 'm')
curve2 = hv.Curve(p,'a','c', label = 'n')    

overlay1 = curve1 * curve2

overlay1.relabel("two curves overlay - legend") + curve1.relabel("single curve - no legend")
```

What can I do to get the legend for one curve?

Comment: I created a github request for this: https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/4196

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly showing a legend is currently (HoloViews 1.13) not possible for just one line/curve.

Only an [Overlay](http://holoviews.org/reference/containers/bokeh/Overlay.html) (= 2 or more lines etc.) shown together in the same plot can have a Legend.

The simplest **workaround** would thus be creating an overlay of the same line:

```
curve1 = hv.Curve([3, 4, 5], name='just one line')
curve1 * curve1
```

**So you put the same line/curve twice in the same plot.**


**Resulting plot:**

[image: one line having a legend by using overlay]